# Shiny renderText: half italicized, half not?

Tags: html, shiny, italics

In my shiny app, I have a textOutput named acronym where I would like to renderText some text which is half non-italicized, half-italicized.

I tried doing it like this:

```
output$acronym_1 <- renderText(paste("SID SIDE:", tags$em("Siderastrea siderea")))
```

But this did not get the second half in italics. How do I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will produce *italicized* text

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(uiOutput("htmlText"))

server <- function(input, output)
  output$htmlText <- renderUI(HTML(paste(
    "Non-italic text.", em("Italic text")
  )))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I don't think `textOutput` is capable of text markup since the output string will be created by `cat` according to the documentation.

> **renderText**(*expr*, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE,
>     outputArgs = list())
>
> *expr*    An expression that returns an R object that can be used as an argument to *cat*.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a bit unclear what renderUI does, but it works!